# Change citation delimiter between works of the same author (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I can change the delimiter between multiple citations in `biblatex` with `\multicitedelim`, but this only applies to citations with different authors. When I have multiple citations with the same author, however, it seems to print a comma every time. As in the example below, this can be very confusing if you use another symbol, e.g. a semicolon `;` as your citation delimiter, and a comma as your page delimiter.

How can I set the delimiter between citations of the same author to be the same as the delimiter between different authors?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "My really long book on my life",
    YEAR = "1971",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PUBLISHER = "Penny Lane Press"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Music -- why I make it",
    YEAR = "1973",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Johnny Smith"}
@BOOK{mccartney1979,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Penny Lane is still in my ears",
    YEAR = "1979",
    LOCATION = "New York",
    PUBLISHER = "Peter Alden"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites[282, 1967]{lennon1971}{lennon1973}{mccartney1979}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you like `\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}`?

Comment: Yes, I would like that very much ``:P`` Feel free to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`biblatex` provides a host of delimiters, amongst them are (definitions from `biblatex.def`)

```
\newcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\newcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\supercitedelim}{\addcomma}
```

What you want is probably `\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "My really long book on my life",
    YEAR = "1971",
    LOCATION = "Liverpool",
    PUBLISHER = "Penny Lane Press"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Music -- why I make it",
    YEAR = "1973",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Johnny Smith"}
@BOOK{mccartney1979,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Penny Lane is still in my ears",
    YEAR = "1979",
    LOCATION = "New York",
    PUBLISHER = "Peter Alden"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites[282, 1967]{lennon1971}{lennon1973}{mccartney1979}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]